# Video editor for macOS that lets you put gifs on top of video

Tags: video, video-editing, macos

I want to edit simple video with as little effort and time as possible. I just need cutting and being able to insert GIFs, preferably like clip art (that would be the most convenient if there's a built-in GIF browser), on top of the video.